# MVC5 js bundle gzip not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, gzip

I have read every article about this on google that I can find and still cant seem to figure out why .js file bundles generated by bundling doesnt seem to get the gzip love.
i even added the following to my web.config

```
 <system.webServer>
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".js" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript" />
</staticContent>
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
```

I assume this is not working because the genreated mimeType is not present by what the bundler creates.. here is one of the bundles which does not have the type generaed. I am not sure if by default IIS 8 treats it as text/javascript or not

```
   <script src="/bundles/modernizr?v=wBEWDufH_8Md-Pbioxomt90vm6tJN2Pyy9u9zHtWsPo1"></script>
   <script src="/bundles/jquery?v=FVs3ACwOLIVInrAl5sdzR2jrCDmVOWFbZMY6g6Q0ulE1"></script>
```

gzip seem to work for everything else on the site, except .js files

Running this on a windows 2012 box

Comment: Have you checked if dynamic content compression module is installed on server?